# Melt with empty list

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have a list in the form of

```
lst=list(NULL, list(a=2, b=3), list(a=4, b=5))
```

When I use melt (from reshape2), I get the following error:

```
melt(lst)
Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

which I guess it comes from the NULL object. I want to use dcast later so I can have a data frame. Is there a way to force melt (or any other way), so at the end I have a data frame as

```
   a  b
1 NA NA
2  2  3
3  4  5
```

where the first observation (the NULL part) is given NA.

Thanks!

Comment: @Sotos Sorry for that, did not find that solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it as well:

```
lst[sapply(lst, is.null)] <- NA
do.call(rbind, lst)
#     a  b 
#[1,] NA NA
#[2,] 2  3 
#[3,] 4  5
```

Or further, into a data frame with `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))`

Comment: did you run it? It does not give expected output

Comment: You were right, check the edit.